# Struct reference lifetime issue during construction of the structure

Tags: rust, reference, lifetime

I have issue with lifetimes and references. I have three structs:

```rust
struct Foo<'a> {
    bar: Bar,
    lar: Lar<'a>
}
   
struct Bar;
    
struct Lar<'a> {
    bar: &'a Bar
}
```

I want to create the final structure like this:

```rust
Foo {
    bar: Bar::new(),
    lar: Lar::new(&bar); // use the reference to bar created above
}
```

I tried two approaches:
1.

```rust
fn main() {
    let bar = Bar::new();
    Foo {
        bar,
        lar: Lar::new(&bar) // at this point the scope of bar is still just the function block, 
        // I get: returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
    }
}
```

2. 

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo {
        bar: Bar::new(),
        ..Default::default() // even if I use @[derive(Default)] on all the structs, 
        //I still get: the trait `std::default::Default` is not implemented for `&Bar`, 
        //I think the problem is that its a referrence not the actuall structure
    };
    foo.lar = Lar::new(&foo.bar);
    foo
}
```

How would I solve this? Thank you

Comment: This is a well-known problem in rust, called the "self-referencing struct" problem. It usually means you have either a design issue or too many levels of indirection. There's no way to fix this as is without unsafe and pin. There are libraries that tried to solve this problem, but some of them had soundness issues. I'd recommend you find another way.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I see, thank you for explaining. Originally I wanted to make Bar a singleton, but I had read that it is a bad practice and I should rather be handing it through as a reference...